# Unmarshal JSON-Array to object while ignoring null values

Tags: java, json, jackson, deserialization

I get a JSON-Object as an array form an external source which looks like this:
`[13823108,"Text1","Text2",null,null,1585730520000,1585753742000,null,null,"COMPLETED",null]`

The array will always have `null` values at those positions, which is why I would like to ignore those.

My Java object is suppose to look like this:

```
@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.ARRAY)
public class MyJsonObject {
  private final String id;
  private final String textField1;
  private final String textField2;
  private final Date started;
  private final Date updated;
  private final String status;

  @JsonCreator
  public MyJsonObject(
      @JsonProperty("id") final String id,
      @JsonProperty("textField1") final String textField1,
      @JsonProperty("textField2") final String textField2,
      @JsonProperty("started") final Date started,
      @JsonProperty("updated") final Date updated,
      @JsonProperty("status") final String status) {
    this.id = id;
    this.textField1 = textField1;
    this.textField2 = textField2;
    this.started = started;
    this.updated = updated;
    this.status = status;
  }
[...]
}
```

When I try to unmarshal the Json the `null` values are used, which courses the additional values to be ignored:

```
MyJsonObject{id='13105603', textField1='Text1', textField2='Text2', started=null, updated=null, status='1569348774000'}
```

Is there a way to tell the ObjectMapper to ignore `null` values of the array? Can I achieve this without writing a specific Deserializer?

I already tried `@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)` with no effect.

Comment: Did you try @JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL) at class level or field level? There is basic tutorial explaining this [here](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-ignore-null-fields) and [here](https://mkyong.com/java/jackson-how-to-ignore-null-fields/)

Comment: I tried both, at class and field level, with no effect. Since my object is an immutable I can't place `@JsonInclude[...]` at the setters.